# Не передаются данные POST - запроса в контроллер

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Не получается передать данные из формы в контроллер, вместо введённой строки передаётся null.

Сама форма:

```
    <div class="text-center">
    <h1 >Welcome</h1>
    <form asp-action="DataResponse" asp-controller="Home">
        <label>Валюта:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="nameCurrency" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Метод контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DataResponse(string nameCurrency)
    {
        Cash csh = new Cash(); //Dictionary<string,Currency>
        csh.CashValues.Add("Rub",new Currency("руб","RUB",43.89,DateTime.Now));
        if (csh.CashValues.ContainsKey(nameCurrency) &&
            DateTime.Now.Hour - csh.CashValues[nameCurrency]._TimeResponse.Hour < 1)
        {
            ViewBag.CurName = csh.CashValues[nameCurrency]._Name;
            ViewBag.CurCourse = csh.CashValues[nameCurrency]._Course;
            return View();
        }
        /*request*/
        ViewBag.CurName = csh.CashValues[nameCurrency]._Name;
        ViewBag.CurCourse = csh.CashValues[nameCurrency]._Course;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: может <input type="text" name ="nameCurrency" /> ?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, всё заработало. Спасибо